# Visual C++ 2010 cannot Step Into MFC source

Tags: mfc, symbols, visual-c++-2010, pdb-files, step-into

I've been trying several solutions available on the Internet for this, but none of them worked.

I can not step into any method of the MFC Source code.

In my Output Window I see:

```
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp.exe', Symbols loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib1.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfc100ud.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcomp100d.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.18120_none_72d2e82386681b36\GdiPlus.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wsock32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib4.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcLayers.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-ole32-l1-1-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\normaliz.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l2-1-0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll'
MyLib2.DLL Initializing!
MyLib3.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-da-DK.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-da-DK.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-en-GB.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-en-GB.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-ja-JP.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-ja-JP.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-ko-KR.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-ko-KR.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-pt-PT.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-pt-PT.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-zh-CHS.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-zh-CHS.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll', Exports loaded.
NestingEngineLib.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver1.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver1.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver2.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver2.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver3.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver3.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver4.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver4.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver5.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver5.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver6.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver6.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver7.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver7.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver8.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver8.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver9.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver9.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x5280000', Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'ImageAtBase0x5280000'
MyDriver2.DLL Terminating!
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver2.drv'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver10.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver10.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver11.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver11.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver12.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver12.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver13.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver13.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver14.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver14.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver15.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver15.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver16.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver16.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver17.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver17.drv Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\wbemprox.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbemcomn.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\wbemsvc.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\fastprox.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdsapi.dll', Exports loaded.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x29ec) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nlaapi.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\NapiNSP.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\pnrpnsp.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winrnr.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FWPUCLNT.DLL', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WSHTCPIP.DLL', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wship6.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-da-DK.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-da-DK.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-en-GB.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-en-GB.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-ja-JP.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-ja-JP.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-ko-KR.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-ko-KR.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-pt-PT.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-pt-PT.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-zh-CHS.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-zh-CHS.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyApp-en-GB.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-en-GB.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-en-GB.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-ja-JP.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-ja-JP.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-ko-KR.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-ko-KR.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-pt-PT.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-pt-PT.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-zh-CHS.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-zh-CHS.dll'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib2-en-GB.dll', Exports loaded.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyLib3-en-GB.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
Warning: no document names in string for template #1309.
Warning: no document names in string for template #1309.
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver2.drv', Symbols loaded.
MyDriver2.DLL Initializing!
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x5ec0000', Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'ImageAtBase0x5ec0000'
MyDriver2.DLL Terminating!
'MyApp.exe': Unloaded 'd:\src\output\Win32\Debug_Unicode\MyDriver2.drv'
'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsCodecs.dll', Exports loaded.
1'MyApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml3.dll', Exports loaded.
Warning: no document names in string for template #1309.
Warning: no document names in string for template #1309.
```

The strange thing here is: All the other system Libraries say "Exports loaded." , but mfc100ud.dll says "Cannot find or open the PDB file".

It seems a missing of a PDB file, but I have it. Or at least I think I have it.

My Symbols Configuration:
[image: My Symbols Configuration]

My Directories:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib

[image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64
[image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\ia64
[image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\ia64]

C:\Windows\symbols\dll
[image: C:\Windows\symbols\dll]

This is what happened when I did put a Breakpoint on method of a theme class I overwrote. The call stack pane is full of mfcu100ud.dll lines instead of having the methods that are calling my function. If I click some of these lines, all I see is a Disassembly window!
[image: Step Into: OnDrawDefaultRibbonImage]

And in another App, I tried to Step Into CMFCOutlookBarPane::Create but all I see is a Window with names of functions and memory addresses instead of real source code:
[image: Step Into CMFCOutlookBarPane::Create]

I know that in the past I could do this, but now I can't. I make an hypothesis this issue comes from a time where I downloaded some symbols to use Windbg for analyzing Memory Dumps, but I am not sure.

Do you see something wrong, like some PDB file missing? Help, please!

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using the Microsoft Symbol Servers for debugging symbols?

Comment: @rrirower: because the original configuration was without them and things worked well. I already tried to Check that box on, but it also did not make the debugger enter into the methods.

Comment: @rirrower: Just tried again to Check that box on, clicked on "Empty Symbol Cache" and did "Load all symbols". Tried with two different apps, to step into the methods, and I can only step into things that are implemented on .h files. Can never step into methods implemented on the .cpp files!

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding files should be installed in the Folder C:\Windows\symbols\dll.

They are installed with the VS-Setup. You may try to repair the VS-Installation...